# Super User will be the first site Stack Exchange rolls out the new Google Analytics 4 analytics setup

Tags: discussion

Google's killing off their current analytics setup, and as such SE needs to transition to a new one.

Super User will be the first site its rolled out on on the week of september 5th, [as per the post on Meta.Stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381668/135565).

There may be some changes and [user concerns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/381671/135565) on the back end. I'd direct any technical queries and issues to the main meta post (simply cause I've no insight into the exact process and roadmap beyond what's there), and well I'm not certain what's the 'official' plan to monitor issues - the goal here is to get our community aware of this as early as possible.

I'll update relevant information (or if you're staff, feel free to edit this or answer) as it's available.